# JavaScript - Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am working on MVC project and I am running into an error when I am trying to open a Bootstrap modal.

The error message I am getting is:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

This is the button with the OnClick call:

```
<button id="btnVenueDelete" onclick="DeleteModal(@item.VenueName, @item.VenueID);" class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Delete</button>
```

This is the JavaScript function:

```
function DeleteModal(name, id) {
        console.log(Name);
        console.log(ID);

        txtModal.innerText = "Delete" + Name;
        $("#VenueModal").modal();
    }
```

I think the problem is due to something in the button as I am not seeing the console logs in the developer console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `item.VenueName` is some **string** value. In that case, make sure to wrap the parameters in quotes.

```
<button id="btnVenueDelete" 
     onclick="DeleteModal('@item.VenueName', '@item.VenueID');" 
     class="btn btn-sm btn-info">Delete</button>
```

Now your code will not break even if the `VenueName` value is a string with space in it (Ex : `"Ann Arbor"`)

I also assumes that `txtModal` inside the method is already defined somewhere before using it.

Also, javascript is **case sensitive**. so make sure you use the correct casing in the variable/argument names.

```
    function DeleteModal(name, id) {
        console.log(name);
        console.log(id);
    }
```

Comment: Yes I defined the modal and your solution worked perfectly thanks